# Using the text value from a dropdownlist in a different view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `@Html.DropDownListFor` in a Create View and I store the value in my model.  My problem is, how do I display this field in a list view?

The field is a status field, so the value is "A" or "T". In the List view I see "A" or "T", but I want to have it display the Text value from the drop down.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Model

```
namespace PershingNetX360Users.Models
{
    public class UserInfo
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public ulong Id { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }

    }
}
```

In my Create View i have

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status,
                           new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = @"Select...",
                    Value = " ",
                    Selected = Model.Status.Equals(" ")
                },
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = @"Active",
                    Value = "A",
                    Selected = Model.Status.Equals("A")
                },
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = @"Terminated",
                    Value = "T",
                    Selected = Model.Status.Equals("T")
                }
            })
```

in my list

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Division)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoginId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pin)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RepId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

is there something else besides the `@Html.DisplayFor()` i can use?  or do i add a second field to my model to store the Text value and use that field in the list?

Comment: Can you provide some things that you've tried? It helps us to see code. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example which will help your question receive answers.

Comment: that's part of the problem, i'm not sure on what to do or where to start.

Comment: Well at least providing the code that you're looking at will help.

Comment: Thanks. Similar to what you mention at the end, I would recommend adding a method to your model to translate the `Status` field to the value that you are looking to display